# How to call a webservice in marionette.js framework CollectionView

Tags: jquery, web-services, backbone.js, marionette, restful-url

The situation is I have an Collection View which Looks like these.

```
ContactManager.module('Entities', function (Entities, ContactManager, Backbone,
    Marionette, $, _) {
    Entities.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({

    });

    Entities.configureStorage(Entities.Contact);

    Entities.ContactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: Entities.Contact,
        comparator: "firstName"
    });

    var contacts;

    var initializeContacts = function () {
        contacts = new Entities.ContactCollection([{
            id: 1,
            firstName: 'Alice',
            lastName: 'Arten',
            phoneNumber: '555-0184'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            firstName: 'Bob',
            lastName: 'Brigham',
            phoneNumber: '555-0163'
        }, {
            id: 3,
            firstName: 'Charlie',
            lastName: 'Campbell',
            phoneNumber: '555-0129'
        }]);
    };

    var API = {
        getContactEntities: function () {

            if (contacts === undefined) {
                initializeContacts();
            }
            return contacts;
        }
    };

    ContactManager.reqres.setHandler("contact:entities", function () {
        return API.getContactEntities();
    });
});
```

Presently I am displaying contacts collection using static values but now I want to populate it by calling an restful web service which will return a json. I have tried a lot of things but not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work:

```
Entities.ContactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Entities.Contact,
    comparator: "firstName",
    // this is the API that returns a JSON list of contacts 
    url: '/contacts'
});

var initializeContacts = function () {
    contacts = new Entities.ContactCollection();
    // ask the collection to update itself from the server.
    contacts.fetch();
};
```

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer +1 for u. Chris can you help me I am not able to show it in a view please.